# Programmatically obtain Embedded Servlet Container Information

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application. I want to display the current Servlet Container name and version in an Admin Console page.

Currently my application uses Tomcat, but I want to automatically display the same information if I were to, say, change to Jetty or some other embedded servlet container.

This information is not available (at least it seems) through the `Environment`, or `Actuator` endpoints.

How can I programmatically obtain the embedded servlet container name and version?

Comment: How are you configuring the servlet; Java, properties?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils properties... and the pom. Almost a default spring boot servlet container, just adjusting port, and a couple minor things. When the application starts, spring logs the servlet engine... (`org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23`), was hoping there was some way to get that information during runtime on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the information you are looking for from the [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

You can autowire it with:

```
@Autowired ServletContext context;
```

and then access the wanted information:

```
context.getServerInfo()
```

In my Spring Boot application with an embedded Tomcat, I obtain the following string:

```
Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
```

Comment: Nice! I'll award bounty when timer expires.